# Number of permutations with precedence constraints : DP case

Tags: co.combinatorics, permutations, enumerative-combinatorics

I have two sets of balls (blacks and whites), each set is numbered from $1$ to $n$, and all are put in a jar. My precedence constraint is expressed as following : to pick a black ball with index $i$, its corresponding white ball (with the same index $i$) must be chosen before. The number of permutations of black and white balls is given by the known "number of ways to put socks and shoes on a spider", which is equal to $(2n)!/2^n$. My question is what is the equivalent number of possibilities for dynamic programming enumeration (for n! permutations, it is known that the total number of solutions is $n*2^n$, which is the spatial complexity of dynamic programming).

Comment: The number you are looking for is $(2n)!/2^n$. This type of question is more suitable over at math.stackexchange.

Comment: http://oeis.org/A000680 "Number of ways to put socks and shoes on an n-legged animal, if a sock must be put on before a shoe."

Comment: Thank you. I have edited the question. I hope it is fine now.